# Dynamic array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am creating an online test page and want to capture wrong answers and push in another array. My code is given below. What am I doing wrong? thanks in advance.

```
var ar, wqs, wqpos = 0;
var oneq = new Array(5);
function renderQuestion()
{
    test = _("test");
  if(pos >= ar.length)
  {
    _("test_status").innerHTML = "Test Completed";
    pos = 0;
    correct = 0;
    wqpos = 0;
    return false;
   }
question = ar[pos][1];
..... rest of code
<input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'> "+chA+"<br>;
...... rest of code
<button onClick='checkAnswer()'>Submit Answer</button>;
}   
 function checkAnswer()
{
choices = document.getElementsByName("choices");
for(var i=0; i<choices.length; i++)
{
    if(choices[i].checked)
    {
        choice = choices[i].value;
    }
}
if(choice == ar[pos][5])
{
    correct++;
}
else
{
oneq = [ar[pos][1], ar[pos][2], ar[pos][3], ar[pos][4], ar[pos][5]];
```

Problem is the next 2 lines:

```
wqs[wqpos] = [oneq[0], oneq[1], oneq[2], oneq[3], oneq[4]];
wqpos++;
}
pos++;
renderQuestion();
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: Problem: When I try to add oneq array to wqs array nothing happens. the program worked fine till I tried to add oneq to wqs.

Answer (score 0):

Sr. I don't understand your question, should i can't fix it.
But, i read your code, i think method renderQuestion() have problem. Because:

```
var ar, wqs, wqpos = 0; // ar is undefined
```

so, in method renderQuestion() check:

```
if(pos >= ar.length) // ar.length is error: Uncaught TypeError, because ar is undefined
```

I think you should set value default for variable.

Thanks.